# G++: calling function from template: undefined symbol

Tags: templates, g++

I can't compile small code in C++ using Comeau and G++ compilers. I think that there is a problem in my code. Here it is:

```
template < typename T > void f(T t) { g(t); }
void g(int){}
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Function `g()` here is not found by compiler.
But if I use a user-defined type (not `int`), it is compiled OK:

```
template < typename T > void f(T t) { g(t); }
struct A {};
void g(A a) {}
int main() {
    A a;
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me to compile this code with int (double, char etc.)?

Comment: In the first code snippet, your template function - `f` - expects an argument that can be of any type.  That type here is labeled `T`.  However, inside that function, you pass a value of type `T` to a function that accepts only integers.  What if `T` isn't the integer type? How on earth could you interpret that?

I suspect that the second code snippet compiles and runs; however, this doesn't change the root of the problem.

In order to make `f` usable for all types, you must either make `g` usable for all types, or make it independent of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related, but in VC++ 2012 this gives an uninitialized variable warning for a in the `int a` line.   The second example (which will *not* compile due to your missing the braces after `void g(A a)`) creates a struct with a default constructor, so the error does not occur. Try to initialise your int variable in the top code and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment. I've added braces, of course, it was a misprint.

Comment: Oh, uninitialized variable is only a warning, and has no influence to the descibed error.

Comment: Seems as though you've identified a bug in the compiler, rather than in your code. Tested fine with GCC 4.6.2 under MingW